# Multiple SwipeableContainers in a single form

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to create a list of SwipeableContainers in a boxlayout on codenameone.

```
list.add(createWidget("Banana")).
            add(createWidget("Apple")).
            add(createWidget("Juice"));

public SwipeableContainer createWidget(String info) {

    MultiButton button = new MultiButton(info);
    return new SwipeableContainer(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(deleteb),button);
    
}
```

Doing this returns an error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already contained in Container: Container[x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 name=null, layout = FlowLayout, scrollableX = false, scrollableY = false, components = [MultiButton]]." This is the same syntax as used on the Codenameone tutorial provided at: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/SwipeableContainer.html. However my code doesn't seem to allow me to create multiple of these components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the `deleteb` button is used by another button. If you modify this code as such it should work:

```
MultiButton button = new MultiButton(info);
Button deleteb = new Button(FontImage.MATERIAL_DELETE);
return new SwipeableContainer(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(deleteb),button);
```